# Kendo ui Grid Footer React

Tags: reactjs, kendo-grid

I am developing an application using kendo ui grid with React Js, and I am facing a problem. I want to make a calculated footer.  Take the total of column A and the total of column B and divide them.

Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Please consider reading this [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you haven't already. If your question is just text without any code, chances are good that you will find your answer on a searchmachine.
With a code example to show, which could be useful, you could [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please remember that the Stackoverflow community is not a coding service. We will help to solve your coding problems but not generate code for you.

Comment: There is discussion in the kendo-react repository that may give some insights:
https://github.com/telerik/kendo-react/issues/47
It is about how to render global aggregates.